# AngularJs $scope values are not updated from an AJAX callback

Tags: ajax, angularjs, scope, apply

I am trying to set property value on $scope inside of an AJAX callback. Actually, I am trying to set it inside of a nested AJAX callback.

See the code below.

```
equipmentService.deleteItem($scope.idToDelete).success(function (response) {
    if (response) {
        equipmentService.updateList($scope.listDetail).success(function (response) {
            if (response) {
                $scope.selectedId = null;
                $scope.$apply();
                $scope.alerts.push({ type: 'success', msg: 'Changes saved successfully.' });
            }
        });
    }
};
```

The value of $scope.selectedId is, in fact null inside the callback block. However, outside of the callback block its value hasn't changed.

Most of my searches on problems like this suggest $scope.$apply as the cure for all AngularJs problems. Unfortunately, I've never been able to get it to do anything at all.

Clearly, I'm missing something here. Can anyone give me a clue?

Comment: *outside of the callback block its value hasn't changed* - where are you trying to access it? Both methods shown are asynchronous.

Comment: From outside of the async methods. There must be something wrong with my code, because I set values this way in other methods inside my controller. This value for some reason retains it's original value.